# Return a File and Navigate to new view or update current view in Asp Mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Need to Return a pdf and update my view.

1)I know request and response working(single response). so any idea or code to hack this will be helpful .

```
if (isSuccess==ProcessFlag.success)
{
 GeneratePdf objGeneratePdf=new GeneratePdf();
 MemoryStream stream = objGeneratePdf.Addpair(objBankDetails);//creating a pdf and return as byte
 return File(stream, "application/pdf", "my.pdf");                        
}
```

My problem is once pdf is generated ,user must navigate to new view.

My view for creating pdf controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BankDetails", "index", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "myform" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10" style="text-align:center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I suggest maybe you cause the download to happen in a new tab. There's no need to use a POST here by the looks of it, you could potentially do it as a GET,. and trigger the opening of a new window (doing a GET to the download URL) via javascript (when the button is clicked) and then redirect the main page to a new view. That's really the only way you can do it - the download will have to be done in a separate HTTP request.

Comment: Inside the form there are some textbox controls .so i guess Post is required .

Comment: give your form a target="_blank" attribute and it will submit to a new window, but not sure that lets you continue within the current window to trigger a navigation as well,